# Create new project on Eclipse with existing Java files

Tags: java, eclipse, compilation, project

I have to develop some Java application. I have already the application structure, so I only have to modify java files to get what I want.

I was compiling and running the Java application with java command. However, I would like to create a project on Eclipse to be able to debug the code and make me easier the delevop work.

I tried to create a new Java project application and import the current Java files. However, I did it wrong and I don't know how to do that. I have this directories estructure:

```
root@vbox:/media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1# ls -d */
applications/  core/  data/  doc/  ee/  gui/  input/  interfaces/  lib/  movement/  report/  reports/  routing/  test/  toolkit/  ui/  wdm_settings/
root@mvbox:/media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1# ls core/
 Application.class           ConnectionListener.class     DTN2Manager.java        MessageListener.java                NetworkInterface.java   SimClock.class      UpdateListener.class
 Application.java            ConnectionListener.java      DTNHost.class           ModuleCommunicationBus.class        package.html            SimClock.java       UpdateListener.java
 ApplicationListener.class   Coord.class                  DTNHost.java            ModuleCommunicationBus.java         ParetoRNG.class         SimError.class      VBRConnection.class
 ApplicationListener.java    Coord.java                   DTNSim.class            ModuleCommunicationListener.class   ParetoRNG.java          SimError.java       VBRConnection.java
 CBRConnection.class         Debug.class                  DTNSim.java             ModuleCommunicationListener.java    Settings.class          SimScenario.class   World.class
 CBRConnection.java          Debug.java                   Message.class           MovementListener.class              SettingsError.class     SimScenario.java    World.java
 Connection.class            DTN2Manager.class            Message.java            MovementListener.java               SettingsError.java      Tuple.class
 Connection.java            'DTN2Manager$EIDHost.class'   MessageListener.class   NetworkInterface.class              Settings.java           Tuple.java
```

The main class is DTNSim.java. There are also some config files in /media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1 directory.

```
root@vbox:/media/sf_shared/one_1.4.1# ls *.txt
cluster_settings.txt  epidemic_settings.txt  LICENSE.txt            prophet_settings.txt  snw_comparison_settings.txt  WDM_conf_help.txt
default_settings.txt  HISTORY.txt            ping_app_settings.txt  README.txt            snw_settings.txt
```

I know that this is a very very noob question, but I really need help because I'm not developer. How can I execute/modify/debug this application with Eclipse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I just create a dir with the same name as a new Java project and eclipse recognize all java files and put it into a structure.

Comment: _File > Open Projects from File System..._ detects source folders (folders containing `.java` files), adds JARs to the _Build Path_ and also detects Maven projects (if the project directory contains a `pom.xml` file). To open a Gradle project use _File > Import: Gradle > Existing Gradle Project_ instead.